# How do I do a copy-and-run deploy of a simple webservice using Kestrel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

We're working on a project part of which involves our writing a client to call a REST web service that our customer will implement.

Said web service is to be developed by the customer according to a specification that we will design. The intent is to create a standard that multiple customers will be able to use, in the future, without our having to modify our client in any way.

Now we have never, in the thirty years I've been working with this company, had a client successfully build a web service according to a predefined specification doesn't change the requirement. Even when we were doing SOAP interfaces, where we would supply the customer with the .wsdl, they still never managed to implement the server correctly.

But we're committed, so I'm trying to do as much hand-holding as possible.

We are writing a client. To test that it works we will need a test implementation of the server. My intent is to create a test server, and a test client, and our actual client, and to provide the customer with both test server and test client, tell them to develop their own server that the test client works against.

What I need, then, is a test web server that a customer an easily install and run, and a test client that can also be easily installed and run.

What would be ideal would be a single exe that could be run from the command line for each, without having to run installers.

We've been a .NET Framework shop, but we've been intending to move to .NET Core in the next year or so.

What I was thinking was that if we could build the test server and client in .NET core that would give future customers more options for running it.

So, the question is, how do I create a simple web service in .NET Core so that it can be run from the command line, without having to configure web servers, firewalls, etc.?

This doesn't to run as a background service, doesn't need to be configured to talk to a database, doesn't need to run on any specific port, etc. It just starts up on a specified port and listens until it's shut down.

E.g;

```
$ mytestserver --port 5432
$ mytestclient http://localhost:5432
```

Ideas?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly you do not have to do anything. A Kestrel based Asp.Net Core server basically *IS* a console application that can be started/run like any other executable.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://jonhilton.net/2016/07/18/your-first-net-core-web-application-using-nothing-but-the-command-line/) is a basic hello world application but this is old version of .net core i.e. 1.1. New one wouldn't differ much with the basic logic.

For the ports and configuration you have to look up in the documentation on how to specify the ports. You basically would be using AppSettings.json. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1) is more info on profiles and appsettings.